# Kafka Consumer not receiving all messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm benchmarking my application (a REST API written in Java) that uses Apache Kafka - for simplicity, let's say that a message is sent to Kafka, and it is echoed back on another topic by a different application.

On a benchmark of 100,000 requests, 116 failed to make it back to my app. Using `kafkacat` as a consumer on the same topic, though, the offset after all of the messages had been received is exactly 100,000 more than before I started the benchmark (no messages lost).

Is there something about the Kafka Java Consumer API that's causing it to not receive all of the messages? Is there anything that can be done, or is it just inevitable?

EDIT:

Flow: HTTP server -> topic 1 -> app that sends another message -> topic 2 -> HTTP server

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the flow.  Is this it:

    "message -> kafka topic1 -> your app -> kafka topic2"

Then you run kafkacat on topic1 and it shows that offset is 100,000, but your app does not receive 116 of those messages (do you check topic2 offset for that?).

Comment: You got the flow right except that the same app that sent the message is also at the very end receiving from topic 2. I run kafkacat on topic2 and it shows the correct offset, but the aforementioned app at the end is missing 116 messages.

Comment: How do you verify that there are missing messages in the app?

Comment: The HTTP requests that correspond to the missing messages just time out after 30 seconds.